# String operator like std::string

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, operators

Say I have a function:

```
void foo(const std::string& str);
```

I could call that function:

```
foo("my string");
```

How does `std::string` accept a string in place of the type? Is it an overloaded operator? I'm making my own string class, and this feature is essential.

Comment: `std::string` has a non-explicit constructor which takes a `const char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a call

```
foo("my string");
```

the compiler has to go through various steps to decide which function call that should resolve to.

1. Find out all the functions `foo` in the given scope.
2. If there are more than one functions named `foo`, it will try to find all the viable functions that can be called with the given argument. If there are more than one matches, it will try to find the best match given the arguments. If there is only one viable, function, then the compiler proceeds. If there are no viable functions, there will be a compile error.
3. If there is only one function named `foo`, it will try to see if the argument used to call the function matches the argument type. If yes, then the compiler proceeds. If not, there will be a compiler error.

The logic for figuring out whether an argument matches the arguments types of a function is too long to describe here. You can read more about it at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion.

In your case, `"my string"` can be converted to a `std::string` by using a constructor of `std::string`. The call

```
foo("my string");
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo(std::string("my string"));
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it's all up to the compiler?

Comment: @OliverYasuna, yes but the compiler has to follow what the standard dictates.

Comment: Darn, so I wont be able to create my own string class that does this. Thank you

Comment: @OliverYasuna Sure you can, just have a non-explicit constructor that takes a `const char*`.

Comment: Oh duh. I got caught up in my own confusion